# Remote JS Debug Enabled - cached bundle

Tags: react-native

This is really weird I can't explain it.

On Android, I have my device. I connected it via USB debugging. Things were working fine last night. Now, when i have remote debugging enabled, its using a cached version of the bundle or something, because my changes are not coming through.

I did a `cd android` and `./gradlew clean` and then restarted metro bundler, run-android, and even restarted device. However no matter what, if remote debugging is enabled, its using an old bundle and not reflecting my newest changes.

Its even more weird because I have "live reload" enabled and whenever I save it does trigger a reload of the app, but its not with my newest changes!

Does anyone know whats going on and how to fix?

Comment: Do you see in your metro bundler logs anything related to the bundling phase (i.e. "Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  100.0% (1085/1085), done.") ?

Comment: @FidanHakaj yes i see it.

Comment: I would suggest you to read following: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#connecting-to-the-development-server

Comment: @FidanHakaj thanks I re-read that now, but its not helping figure out this cached bundle issue it is so confusing. It's never happend to me in 10 months of RN dev.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete folder android/build, it helped for me

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I actually restarted my computer and it fixed it surprisingly.

Answer (score 1):

I had it too - cleaning my Chrome’s cache solved the problem for me!